# How do you add a rightNavButton to an iOS app when using Titanium Alloy?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to create a rightNavButton for a window.

The code in my view looks something like this:

```
<Alloy>
  <Window title="TabName" id="myWindow">
    <Label>Text</Label>
    <Button id="topRight">Foo</Button>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I was trying to come up with a way to set the rightNavButton of the window to something, and thought setting the property in the controller would be the way to go. I can get a button to be in the top right, but it will always exist in the window as well.

```
$.myWindow.rightNavButton = $.topRight;
```

I've thought about creating a separate view for the button and requiring it somehow, but I'm not sure how to do that. I'm not even sure if that's the proper thing to do.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Edit:

I sort of have a workaround now.

```
$.myWindow.rightNavButton = Ti.UI.createButton({title: 'topRight'});
```

That code in the controller works, but it seems to defeat the whole point of using alloy. Now that button will no longer exist in the XML file.

Comment: [Retagged as alloy-ui to avoid confusion with the light-weight formal methods tool developed at MIT, which is what the 'alloy' tag denotes.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at my project here https://github.com/aaronksaunders/alloy_fugitive

I add the button to the view.xml and then just set it in the controller

```
$.fugitiveWindow.setRightNavButton($.add);
```

in the view.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Tab id="fugitiveTab" title="Fugitives">
        <Window id="fugitiveWindow"  title="Fugitives" class='container'>
            <TableView id="table"/>
            <!-- hidden and used later -->
            <Button id="add" title="Add" top="-50dp"></Button>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: That looks like it would work. It would still have a second instance of that button existing though, right?

If the controller isn't being used elsewhere, I assume it would be better to explicitly invoke Ti.UI.createButton.

Comment: why would there be a second instance of the button... it is just using the same button in the navigation bar. There is no new object being created

Comment: I wasn't being clear enough. My concern was that resources would be spent drawing another rendering of the button onto the screen (albeit, out of visible range). Still, I suppose it's a trivial matter in the end.